# How can I make a navigation code in javascript for this image gallery?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an image gallery code and i'm trying to make a javascript function that will jump to a different slide after a set time (in this case 6 seconds).  I'm very confused about how to make it work.  Below is the HTML code of the image gallery.

The function im trying to make is the 'SetTimeout (jump, 6000)' for the onclick in the navigation. The purpose of it is so that when the user clicks "prev" or "next" they are directed to the next slide, but after 6 seconds they are sent to a different slide.

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated, ive been searching for a while now to figure out how to do it, but I don't have enough experience to figure it out.

```html
<ul class="slides">
 <div class="page-header" id="page-header">
 
 <!--Begin slide 1 -->
 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />

    <li class="slide-container">

  <div class="slide">
   <video id="video1" width="100%" autoplay loop muted >
   <source src="files/video/1.webm" type="video/webm">     
    </video>
        </div>

  <div class="nav">
  
   <label for="img-3" class="prev" onclick="setTimeout(jump, 6000);"></label>
   <label for="img-2"  class="next" onclick="setTimeout(jump2, 6000);" ></label>

  </div>

    </li>
<!-- End slide 1 -->
 
 
 <!--Begin slide 2 --> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
<div class="video-container">

        <div class="slide">
  <video id="video2" width="100%"   muted >
          <source src="files/video/2.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    </video>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-1" class="prev"  onclick="setTimeout(jump3, 6000);"></label>
   <label for="img-3" class="next"  onclick="setTimeout(jump4, 6000);"></label>

  </div>  
    </li>
 <!--End slide 2 -->
 
 <!--Begin slide 3 -->
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />

    <li class="slide-container">
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="slide">
  
  <video id="video3" width="100%" >
          <source src="files/video/3.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    </video>
    </div>
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-2" class="prev" onclick="setTimeout(jump5, 6000);"></label>
   <label for="img-1" class="next" onclick="setTimeout(jump6, 6000);"></label>
  </div>
    </li>
 <!--End slide 3 -->

</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: So can you elaborate on exactly what your issue is?  e.g. what is not working?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I'm trying to make a javascript function for the HTML code I posted but I have no idea how.  The function im trying to make is the 'SetTimeout (jump, 6000)' for the onclick in the navigation. The purpose of it is so that when the user clicks "prev" or "next" they are directed to the next slide, but after 6 seconds they are sent to a different slide.  I just have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the definition of your **jump callback**? And also in creating image gallery, you don't need to add the **nav component** on each slide. It should have only one instance on your image slider.

My snippet on creating simple image gallery:

```
 <ul class="slide-gallery">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <!-- elements on each slide -->

    </li>
    <li class="slide-container">
        <!-- elements on each slide -->

    </li>
    <li class="slide-container">
        <!-- elements on each slide -->        
    </li> 
</ul>
<!-- use for navigating on each slide -->
<div class="slide-nav">
    <div class="prev"> 
    </div>
    <div class="next"> 
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- also use for navigating -->
<div class="slide-dots">
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use this snippet or I will suggest to search some image gallery or carousel plugin. There are different plugins that will suit your needs. Based on the outcome that you want to achieve, I would suggest owl plugins - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ . There are a lot of styles that you can use like auto-play, responsive image gallery and lot more.

Comment: The nav component is on each slide to specify which slide they will go to, I need this for a specific purpose in my project.  What I mean by "jump" is that the user is directed to a different slide.  When the user clicks on "prev" or "next" they are directed to that slide, but after 6 seconds they are automatically directed to a different slide defined in the "jump" function.  This will be the "setTimeout(jump, 6000);" that is activated onclick.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding inline JavaScript, so that you can add more complex functionality. Think about the following ideas:

- When a new image is displayed, an timer (interval) going to the next image should be set (`setTimeout`).
- The current timer should be cleared when the user hits a prev/next button. To call `clearTimeout`, you need to pass in the *intervalID*, which is returned from `setTimeout`.

I would store the current intervalID in a variable, and I would suggest using one function with an argument, instead of six functions:

```
var timer;
...
// an example click event handler for a prev/next button
prev1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    displayImage(3);
});
function displayImage(index) {
    // load index image
    var nextIndex = index<3 ? index+1 : 0;
    timer = setTimeout(nextIndex, 6000); // get ready to display next image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I really just need to make an inline javascript code that will work with the HTML I posted.  There is already a navigation system in the HTML code, I just need to make a secondary inline javascript navigation function for a specific purpose.  The function I am trying to make is 'setTimeout(jump, 6000);' in the HTML code.  I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks "prev" or "next", they will go to that slide, but after 6 seconds they will be directed to a different slide that is defined in the setTimeout function.  If you have ideas i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2454060 I don't know if you can do that with just inline function calls.